# how to populate an observable array from two different arrays in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

Within my app I have a section that allows users to add a filter for search criteria the filter is an observable array that contains 3 drop down menus and input fields for manually adding values. Two of the drop down menus are static, the third is populated based upon selected items located elsewhere in the page. Where I am having trouble is in the binding between the two array's. I have all the drop downs populating but I cannot figure out how to pass the value from the SelectedAttributes() array to be inserted in the attribure property of my filter list

html

```
<input type="button" value="Add Filter" title="Add Filter" data-bind="click: $root.addFilter, enable: myfilters().length < 10" />
<table>
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: myfilters">
  <tr>
  <td>
    <!-- ko with: $root.iqReport -->
    <select data-bind="options: SelectedAttributes(), optionsText: function(SelectedAttributes){ return SelectedAttributes.NameHierarchy() + '.' + SelectedAttributes.LabelName() },  optionsCaption:'Select a Field...'">
    </select>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </td>
  <td>
    <select data-bind="options: $root.filterOperators, value:operator, optionsText: 'operatorName'">
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input data-bind="value: criteria1" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input data-bind="value: criteria2" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <select data-bind="options: $root.joinOperators, value:joinOperator, optionsText: 'joinName'">
    </select>
 </td>
 <td>
    <a class="attributeLink" data-bind="click: $root.removeFilter">Remove</a>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

knockoutJS

```
function FilterList(JoiningOperator, AttributeHierarchy, AttributeIDHierarchy, Operator, FilterCriteria, FilterCriteriaRange) {
    var self = this;

    self.joinOperator = ko.observable(JoiningOperator);
    self.attribute = ko.observable(AttributeHierarchy);
    self.attributeID = ko.observable(AttributeIDHierarchy);
    self.operator = ko.observable(Operator);
    self.criteria1 = ko.observable(FilterCriteria);
    self.criteria2 = ko.observable(FilterCriteriaRange);
}


var viewmodel function(){

        //non-editable operators
        self.filterOperators = [
        { operatorName: "EQUALS", operatorValue: "=" },
        { operatorName: "GREATER THAN", operatorValue: ">" },
        { operatorName: "GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO", operatorValue: ">=" },
        { operatorName: "LESS THAN", operatorValue: "<" },
        { operatorName: "LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO", operatorValue: "<=" },
        { operatorName: "NOT EQUAL TO", operatorValue: "<>" },
        { operatorName: "NOT LESS THAN", operatorValue: "!>" },
        { operatorName: "NOT GREATER THAN", operatorValue: "!<" },
        { operatorName: "BETWEEN", operatorValue: "BETWEEN" },
        { operatorName: "LIKE", operatorValue: "LIKE" }
        ];

        //non-editable joins
        self.joinOperators = [
        {joinName: "AND"},
        {joinName: "OR"}
        ];


        //define filter collection
        self.myfilters = ko.observableArray([]);


        //add new filter row
        self.addFilter = function () {
            self.myfilters.push(new FilterList(self.joinOperators[0], "", "", self.filterOperators[0], "", ""));
        };

        FilterList.attribute.subscribe(function () {

        }, FilterList);


        self.removeFilter = function (row) {
            self.myfilters.remove(row);
        };
}
```

The collection iqReports is populated from another array independent of myfilters[] hence the virtual binding in the html.

What I would like to learn is when a user selects a value from the Selected attributes drop down how do I go about having that value populate/update the observable property `self.attribute` of myfilters

**Update**

the iqReports collection is an observable array consisting of additional observable arrays.This is created server side, and passed back to the client. The SelectedAttributes class contains the following properties

```
public class ReportEntity
    {
        public int EntityId { get; set; 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string IconPath { get; set; }
        public List<ReportAttribute> PrimaryAttributes { get; set; }
        public List<ReportAttribute> SecondaryAttributes { get; set; }
        public List<ReportAssociatedEntity> AssociatedEntities { get; set; }
        public string Hierarchy { get; set; }
        public string NameHierarchy { get; set; }
        public ReportEntity() 
        {
            // Initialize the attributes lists.
            PrimaryAttributes = new List<ReportAttribute>();
            SecondaryAttributes = new List<ReportAttribute>();

            // Initialize Associated Entities list.
            AssociatedEntities = new List<ReportAssociatedEntity>();
        }
    }


public class ReportAttribute
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string LabelName { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public bool IsSortedBy { get; set; }
        public int SortPosition { get; set; }
        public bool SortAscending { get; set; }
        public bool IsGroupedBy { get; set; }
        public string NameHierarchy { get; set; }
        public string Hierarchy { get; set; }
        public ReportAttribute() { }
    }
```

Once back in the client you can navigate to the values using Firebug in this manner `self.iqReport().SelectedAttributes()[0]().FieldName` I think where the reference is getting lost is because I have it nested inside of another observable array (myfilters) which is why I have the virtual binding wrapped around the section that pertains to iqReports. Removing that with statement breaks the foreach because it cannot resolve the property SelectedAttributes() trying to explicitly path it using $root does not work resulting in none of the drop downs being populated. Firebug at this point would state that it cannot find the property `SelectedAttributes().`

The workaround I introduced was to move the iqReports reference out of the foreach so instead I now have this in the html

```
<!-- ko with: $root.iqReport -->
     <select data-bind="options: SelectedAttributes(), value: $root.selectedItem,  optionsText: function(SelectedAttributes){ return SelectedAttributes.NameHierarchy() + '.' + SelectedAttributes.LabelName() },  optionsCaption:'Select a Field...'">
      </select>
<!-- /ko -->
<input type="button" value="Add Filter" title="Add Filter" data-bind="click: $root.addFilter, enable: myfilters().length < 10" />
<!--<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(iqReport, null, 2)"></pre>-->
<table>
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: myfilters">
       <tr>
          <td>
          <b><span data-bind="text: filterattribute" /></b>
          </td>
          <td>
           <select data-bind="options: $root.filterOperators, value:operator, optionsText: 'operatorName'">
           </select>
          </td>
           <td>
             <input data-bind="value: criteria1" />
           </td>
           <td>
             <input data-bind="value: criteria2" />
           </td>
           <td>
             <select data-bind="options: $root.joinOperators, value:joinOperator, optionsText: 'joinName'">
             </select>
           </td>
           <td>
            <a class="attributeLink" data-bind="click: $root.removeFilter">Remove</a>
            </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then within the view model I added a new observable and setup the mapping for the table as follows

```
 self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

  //define filter collection
 self.myfilters = ko.observableArray([]);


//add new filter row
//Here I navigated to the individual field properties using the selectedItem object
self.addFilter = function () {
            self.myfilters.push(new FilterList(self.joinOperators[0], self.selectedItem().NameHierarchy() + "." + self.selectedItem().FieldName(), "", self.filterOperators[0], "", ""));
        };
```

While this is not my initial preferred approach this does provide a workaround. Using the virtual binding allowed me to populate the select element but I was never able to pass the value of that select back to the myfilters.attribute() observable. I suspect it was due to the foreach but I have no idea how to work around it

-Cheers

Comment: Important details are missing, including: 1. The javascript structure of iqReports/SelectedAttributes (only the C# structure is given).  2. Is SelectedAttributes an array or an object with  ReportEntity and ReportAttribute properties? Both are implied above.  3. How do iqReports/SelectedAttributes get added to your viewmodel?  4. How do iqReports/SelectedAttributes get bound to your markup?  5. What object does $root refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `value` binding and bind it to `self.attribute`, and remove the `with` binding so that the `value` binding can find the `self.attribute`.

So instead of this:

```
<!-- ko with: $root.iqReport -->
    <select data-bind="
        options: SelectedAttributes(), 
        optionsText: function(SelectedAttributes){ 
            return SelectedAttributes.NameHierarchy() + '.' + SelectedAttributes.LabelName() },
        optionsCaption:'Select a  Field...'
    ">
    </select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Do this:

```
<select data-bind="
    options: $root.iqReport.SelectedAttributes(), 
    optionsText: function(SelectedAttributes){ 
        return SelectedAttributes.NameHierarchy() + '.' + SelectedAttributes.LabelName() 
    },  
    optionsCaption:'Select a Field...',
    value: attribute 
">
```

Comment: Removing the virtual binding breaks the entire control of all bindings. Specifically using the $root.iqReport.SelectedAttributes does not work.

Comment: You will need to correct that reference to point that to the proper place in your viewmodel where `SelectedAttributes` exists.  At this point I'm guessing where that should point, because I don't know what your full viewmodel looks like.  Can you provide the entire viewmodel, including iqReport and SelectedAttributes?  Or provide a fiddle demonstrating the problem?   What do you mean when you say that it 'breaks the entire control of all bindings'?  What do you see in the console?

Comment: I have updated the question with more detail. I didn't setup a fiddle as there are some ajax dependencies and stubbing in code does not give an accurate representation of the object.